# How to reduce the memory consumption in GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter effect?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm using `GPUImage` framework implementation `GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter` effect.

Now `GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter` effect has been achieved,but there is too much memory consumption.I know through the `forceProcessingAtSize` method can reduce some memory consumption, but reduce memory consumption too little.

If the `processImage` method is not called, the memory consumption will reduce a lot, so how to use another method to replace it?

How to reduce memory consumption?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GPUImage.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
  UIImageView *captureImageView;
  UIScrollView *scrollView;
  GPUImageView *imageViewGpu;
  GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter *filter;
  BOOL filterFalg;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// create scrollView
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
scrollView.bounces = NO;

// create imageView
captureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
captureImageView.frame = self.view.frame;
captureImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

// add filter to imagePic
GPUImagePicture *imagePic = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:captureImageView.image smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
filter = [[GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter alloc] init];
[imagePic addTarget:filter];

// create GPUImageView
imageViewGpu = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
imageViewGpu.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageViewGpu.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
imageViewGpu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageViewGpu.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio;
[scrollView addSubview:imageViewGpu];


if (imageViewGpu.frame.size.height>imageViewGpu.frame.size.width) {
    [filter setAspectRatio:imageViewGpu.frame.size.height/imageViewGpu.frame.size.width];
}
else
{
    [filter setAspectRatio:imageViewGpu.frame.size.width/imageViewGpu.frame.size.height];
}


[filter setExcludeCircleRadius:0.0f];
[filter setExcludeCirclePoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
[filter setBlurRadiusInPixels:10];
[filter addTarget:imageViewGpu];

[imagePic processImage];

}  

 @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is displaying the image to the screen, use `-forceProcessingAtSize:` on the first filter in your chain. For large input images, that will dramatically reduce their size in memory.

Also, don't load the same image twice, once for your UIImageView and once for your GPUImagePicture. Instead, I recommend removing the UIImageView and displaying an unfiltered version of your image to a GPUImageView by adding a GPUImageView as a parallel target of your GPUImagePicture. That will save a lot of memory right there for a large picture.

Finally, you're going to get crashes with the above code under ARC, because you're not holding on to your GPUImagePicture anywhere. You need to set your GPUImagePicture as an instance variable or property of your class, or it will be deallocated the instant the above method completes. If you're not using ARC, you're leaking memory all over the place in the above (which could be part of your problem).

Comment: Thank you Brad Larson.I used -forceProcessingAtSize,indeed reduce memory consumption,but only reduce about 8M.(Procedure on running consumes memory 60M).I also remove the UIImageView,but it has no effect.Now the procedure still consumes memory about 52M,which is costing too much.So there are other ways to make a significant reduction in the memory of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old version of GPUImageView then use

```
[filter prepareForImageCapture]
```

or if you are using new version then use

```
[stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
```

Add this method just above

```
[imagePic processImage];
```

which is last line of your code.

Try this, may help you

Comment: Thank you Indrajeet.I try this,but it still consumes large amounts of memory,about 60M.There are other ways to make a significant reduction in the memory of it? For example, reduced to 20M.