# How to add multiple filters to UIImage GPUImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, gpuimage, brightness

I noticed a lot of people asking questions about linking filters with GPUImage. I can't quite figure out how to do it succinctly. Finally got it working tonight. Just wanted to share my code so people can link to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"469453586_640.jpg"];
UIImageView *face = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, faceImage.size.width/2.0, faceImage.size.height/2.0)];
[face setImage:faceImage];
[self.view addSubview:face];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:faceImage];

GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
[brightnessFilter setBrightness:.15];
GPUImageGrayscaleFilter *grayscaleFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];

GPUImagePosterizeFilter *posterizeFilter = [[GPUImagePosterizeFilter alloc] init];
[posterizeFilter setColorLevels:1];


[stillImageSource addTarget:brightnessFilter];
[brightnessFilter addTarget:grayscaleFilter];
[grayscaleFilter addTarget:posterizeFilter];

// these need to be changed if you change the order of your filters
//    [brightnessFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
//    [grayscaleFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[posterizeFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

[stillImageSource processImage];

[face setImage: [posterizeFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer]];
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend directing this to a UIImageView. Instead, use a GPUImageView and target that. The conversion to / from UIImage is expensive and memory-consuming, and going directly to a GPUImageView avoids that.

Comment: I used a GPUImageView and it rendered the image center and with black background. Now being that you invented the thing I'll trust you, but as a product developer UIImageView is the go to, it's what i know and it get the results i want the image is set into the frame i defined. So, if you want people doing that, make it that simple. It was very difficult to get this to work and people will always take the quickest route to the result they want.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest going to each post where people are asking how to do exactly what i just accomplished and correcting them rather than knocking a solution.

Comment: This *is* something I regularly suggest to people (one example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25046492/19679 ), and it can make a huge difference in both performance and memory profile. The black bars you were seeing were due to the default kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio fillMode on GPUImageView. You can set that to either kGPUImageFillModeStretch or kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill to fill the space, but you'd probably want to resize the view to fit the frame of your output image first. Meant no offense by this, it's just that most don't realize how slow UIImageView is.

Comment: I was a little offended, but I was just being a baby. Thanks for the tip! I am going to re-write my example.